# Multiple Axis with Plots.jl

Tags: julia, plots.jl

Is there a way to have the second dataset plot on a separate axis, overlaid on the first plot?

```
using Plots; gadfly(size=(800,400))

plot(Vector[randn(100)], line = ([:green], :step))

plot!(Vector[randn(100)], line = ([:red], :step))
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is now done by adding a `twinx()` argument:

```
plot(rand(10))
plot!(twinx(),100rand(10))
```

[image]

There is, however, some unintentional axis and label behavior:

1. Labels are plotted on top of each other by default
2. xticks are plotted on top of the already existing plot
3. Default colors are not correlated to the total number of series in the subplot

Therefore, I suggest adding some additional arguments:

```
plot(rand(10),label="left",legend=:topleft)
plot!(twinx(),100rand(10),color=:red,xticks=:none,label="right")
```

[image]

There still seems to be an issue correlating all series associated with the subplot at the moment.

Comment: You probably want `legend=:topleft`

Comment: Whoops - that was a typo. Thanks - corrected

Comment: @DisabledWhale, how can we also configure the x-axis range which may not 1:length of y values? Eg. if the range is on 0 to 1 instead

Comment: lifesaver......

Comment: @Vass unfortunately, it is not possible to consider dual x and y axes (see eventually https://stackoverflow.com/a/64179487/10156184 including the comments).

Answer (score 5):

It's easy, but doesn't work with Gadfly.  It should work fine with PyPlot and GR.  Here's an example:

[image]

Comment: Tom, what if I want 2 axis on right and another 2 on left?

Comment: It's not supported directly through Plots, but it could be for backends that support it.  Feel free to open an issue, or even better: submit a PR!

Comment: If anyone found this like me: This key is no longer supported. Currently you can achieve this behaviour through twinx(): https://github.com/tbreloff/Plots.jl/issues/378

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple series you want to plot and want to add your data incrementally, you can do it like this:

```
p = plot()
p_twin = twinx(p)

plot!(p,x,y)
plot!(p_twin,x,y_twin)
```

Answer (score -3):

I can confirm (for GR) using Plots; gr()

[image: screenshot]