# Julia: two x axes for plot of same data

Tags: julia, plotly

For certain functions it is convenient and commonplace to plot one dataset with two x axes. My example at hand is a function of the form `f(T)=A*exp(-H/(R*T))`, which is to be plotted with `1/T` on the x axis and `log(f)` on the y axis. In this form, it conveniently appears as a straight line, but for ease of reading the actual temperature `T` instead of `1/T`, it is common to put the corresponding `T` values on a second x axis in the same plot (which is then of course reversed and also not linearly spaced). How do I achieve this with Julia and Plotly?

Here is an example of the type of plot I try to make. For what it's worth, in Gnuplot the additional second (upper) x-axis would be created with `set link x2 via 1./x inverse 1./x`.
[image: conductivity vs. temperature]

Answer (score 1):

For adding a second Y axis there is a `twinx()` method in the `Plots.jl` package. Unfortunately there is not `twiny()` method that could allow adding a secondary X axis.

However, you can take `twinx()` code and simply transpose it:

```
function twiny(sp::Plots.Subplot)
    sp[:top_margin] = max(sp[:top_margin], 30Plots.px)
    plot!(sp.plt, inset = (sp[:subplot_index], bbox(0,0,1,1)))
    twinsp = sp.plt.subplots[end]
    twinsp[:xaxis][:mirror] = true
    twinsp[:background_color_inside] = RGBA{Float64}(0,0,0,0)
    Plots.link_axes!(sp[:yaxis], twinsp[:yaxis])
    twinsp
end
twiny(plt::Plots.Plot = current()) = twiny(plt[1])
```

And now use it like this:

```
using Plots
plot(1:10,rand(10), label = "randData", ylabel = "Y axis",color = :red, legend = :topleft, grid = :off, xlabel = "Numbers Rand")
p = twiny()
plot!(p,5:15,log.(5:15), label = "log(x)", legend = :topright, box = :on, grid = :off, xlabel = "Log values")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I think it's not quite what I meant, and I didn't manage to modify it in a way to meet my needs. I edited my original post and added an example pic for clarification. The purpose is not to add a second curve with a different x-axis but to show the curve with two x-axes in different units/scalings (in this case inverse temperature and temperature). Note that this also includes reversing the second x-axis.

Comment: I should add, though, that your code is quite valuable in its own right. If there is already a twinx method in Plots, I wonder why twiny was not implemented either. Any plans on your part to try and make your little gem part of the official Plots?

Comment: Yeah - it might be worth making a PR. Regarding what you need to do (updated)  it should be easy - there are functions in Plots for adding custom made ticks - when I have idea how to do it will make a post ;-)