How to plot two X axis using Plots.jl
I want to plot a datetime axis and an integer value X axis using Plots.jl.
plot(1:length(df.datetime), df.closes)
plot!(p, df.datetime, zeros(length(df.datetime)), ticks=:native)


I think you're looking for twiny(). See https://docs.juliaplots.org/stable/gallery/gr/generated/gr-ref063/#gr_ref063.

Maybe helpful? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64176617/julia-two-x-axes-for-plot-of-same-data

I believe that twiny from that my post made some time ago its way to Plots.jl code base :)
